# ngx-chess-board.component.d.ts:75:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'

Tags: javascript, angular, dependencies, angular13

I have an app using ngx-chess-board library and it was working fine locally and on the server but recently I get dependency errors when I try to run npm start locally. I tried different versions of ngx-chess-board but no luck. Deleting node modules did not help. I get the errors below when I run npm start:

```
   Error: node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/ngx-chess-board.component.d.ts:75:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

75     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxChessBoardComponent, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/ngx-chess-board.component.d.ts:76:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

76     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgxChessBoardComponent, "ngx-chess-board", never, { "darkTileColor": "darkTileColor"; "lightTileColor": "lightTileColor"; "showCoords": "showCoords"; "sourcePointColor": "sourcePointColor"; "destinationPointColor": "destinationPointColor"; "legalMovesPointColor": "legalMovesPointColor"; "showLastMove": "showLastMove"; "showLegalMoves": "showLegalMoves"; "showActivePiece": "showActivePiece"; "showPossibleCaptures": "showPossibleCaptures"; "size": "size"; "freeMode": "freeMode"; "dragDisabled": "dragDisabled"; "drawDisabled": "drawDisabled"; "pieceIcons": "pieceIcons"; "lightDisabled": "lightDisabled"; "darkDisabled": "darkDisabled"; }, { "moveChange": "moveChange"; "checkmate": "checkmate"; "stalemate": "stalemate"; }, never, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/ngx-chess-board.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

9     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxChessBoardModule, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/ngx-chess-board.module.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

10     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<NgxChessBoardModule, [typeof i1.NgxChessBoardComponent, typeof i2.PiecePromotionModalComponent], [typeof i3.CommonModule, typeof i4.DragDropModule], [typeof i1.NgxChessBoardComponent]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/ngx-chess-board.module.d.ts:11:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

11     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<NgxChessBoardModule>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/piece-promotion/piece-promotion-modal/piece-promotion-modal.component.d.ts:13:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

13     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<PiecePromotionModalComponent, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/piece-promotion/piece-promotion-modal/piece-promotion-modal.component.d.ts:14:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

14     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<PiecePromotionModalComponent, "app-piece-promotion-modal", never, { "pieceIconInput": "pieceIconInput"; "color": "color"; }, {}, never, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/service/ngx-chess-board.service.d.ts:6:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxChessBoardService, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-chess-board/lib/service/ngx-chess-board.service.d.ts:7:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Library/Mobile Documents/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

7     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<NgxChessBoardService>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --aot --prod",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.5",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.135",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.66",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.0.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/w3c-web-usb": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.4",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.4.3",
    "angular-cc-library": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.0.2",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "apexcharts": "^3.25.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "exec": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-sslify": "^1.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "got": "^11.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.2",
    "ldbutton": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.0.2",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.4",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.8",
    "ng-chartist": "^4.1.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng-thermal-print": "^1.0.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-chess-board": "^2.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "pusher": "^2.2.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
    "readable-stream": "^3.6.0",
    "remote-pay-cloud": "3.1.0",
    "remote-pay-cloud-api": "^4.0.3",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "resize-base64": "^1.0.12",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.13",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  }
}
```

my app.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
// used to create fake backend
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {routing} from './app.routing';

import {AlertComponent} from './_directives';
import {AuthGuard} from './_guards';
import {JwtInterceptor, ErrorInterceptor} from './_helpers';
import {AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService} from './_services';
import {HomeComponent} from './home';
import {LoginComponent} from './login';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register';
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe'
import {MDBBootstrapModule} from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import {YoutubeComponent} from './youtube/youtube.component';
import {ChartOfUserAccountsComponent} from './chart-of-user-accounts/chart-of-user-accounts.component';
import {DropdownUserRolesComponent} from './dropdown-user-roles/dropdown-user-roles.component';
import {VideosListComponent} from './videos-list/videos-list.component';
import {VideosSearchComponent} from './videos-search/videos-search.component';
import {VideosPlaylistComponent} from './videos-playlist/videos-playlist.component';
import {VideoDurationPipe} from './shared/pipes/video-duration.pipe';
import {VideoPlayerComponent} from './video-player/video-player.component';
import {VideoLikesViewsPipe} from './shared/pipes/video-likes-views.pipe';
import {VideoNamePipe} from './shared/pipes/video-name.pipe';
import {LazyScrollDirective} from './shared/directives/lazy-scroll/lazy-scroll.directive';
import {YoutubeApiService} from './shared/services/youtube-api.service';
import {YoutubePlayerService} from './shared/services/youtube-player.service';
import {PlaylistStoreService} from './shared/services/playlist-store.service';
import {NotificationService} from './shared/services/notification.service';
import {BrowserNotificationService} from './shared/services/browser-notification.service';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import {HelpComponent} from './help/help.component';
import {CreateUserComponent} from './create-user/create-user.component';
import { AddCategoryComponent } from './add-category/add-category.component';
import { CategoriesComponent } from './categories/categories.component';
import {DropdownCategoriesComponent} from './dropdown-categories/dropdown-categories.component';
import { AddItemComponent } from './add-item/add-item.component';
import {CartService} from './_services/cart.service';
import { ViewCartComponent } from './view-cart/view-cart.component';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { ItemsByCategoryComponent } from './items-by-category/items-by-category.component';
import { ItemsPageComponent } from './items-page/items-page.component';
import { OrderHistoryComponent } from './order-history/order-history.component';
import { DropdownBooleanSelectorComponent } from './dropdown-boolean-selector/dropdown-boolean-selector.component';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import {DropdownItemOptionSelectorComponent} from './dropdown-item-option-selector/dropdown-item-option-selector.component';
import { ViewOrdersComponent } from './view-orders/view-orders.component';
import { TableSummaryComponent } from './table-summary/table-summary.component';
import { DropdownTableSelectorComponent } from './dropdown-table-selector/dropdown-table-selector.component';
import { DropdownFilterByItemSelectorComponent } from './dropdown-filter-by-item-selector/dropdown-filter-by-item-selector.component';
import { DropdownFilterByCategorySelectorComponent } from './dropdown-filter-by-category-selector/dropdown-filter-by-category-selector.component';
import {SidebarMenuComponent} from './sidebar-menu/sidebar-menu.component';
import { ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent } from './item-options-dialog-component/item-options-dialog-component.component';
import { NotificationPopupComponent } from './notification-popup/notification-popup.component';
import {NotifierModule, NotifierOptions} from 'angular-notifier';
import { OrderHistoryDataTableComponent } from './order-history-data-table/order-history-data-table.component';
import { ServerOrderComponent } from './server-order/server-order.component';
import {NotificationConfirmationComponentComponent} from './notification-confirmation-component/notification-confirmation-component.component';
import { WaiterReadyOrderViewComponent } from './waiter-ready-order-view/waiter-ready-order-view.component';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { DropdownLanguageSelectorComponent } from './dropdown-language-selector/dropdown-language-selector.component';
import { CustomMessageItemDialogComponent } from './custom-message-item-dialog/custom-message-item-dialog.component';
import { KioskComponent } from './kiosk/kiosk.component';
import {CloverAuthenticationService} from './_services/cloverAuthentication.service';
import { CategoriesByItemComponent } from './categories-by-item/categories-by-item.component';
import { UploadImageDialogComponent } from './upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component';
import {LogoutComponent} from './logout/logout.component';
import {addTipComponent} from './add-tip/add-tip.component';
import {paymentReceiptComponent} from './payment-receipt/payment-receipt.component';
import {PrinterListComponent} from './printer-list/printer-list.component';
import { PaymentPendingScreenComponent } from './payment-pending-screen/payment-pending-screen.component';
import { CreditCardDirectivesModule } from 'angular-cc-library';
import { CreditCardPaymentScreenComponent } from './credit-card-payment-screen/credit-card-payment-screen.component';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {Provider, Type} from '@angular/core';
import {ThermalPrintModule} from 'ng-thermal-print';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {ChartistModule} from 'ng-chartist';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { NgApexchartsModule } from 'ng-apexcharts';
import {AutosizeModule} from 'ngx-autosize';
import {ServerRequestService} from './_services/serverRequest.service';
import {AuthGuardClover} from './_guards/authClover.guard';;
import { GamesComponent } from './games/games.component';
import {NgxChessBoardModule} from 'ngx-chess-board';
import { CloverAuthRouterComponent } from './clover-auth-router/clover-auth-router.component';


const customNotifierOptions: NotifierOptions = {
  position: {
    horizontal: {
      position: 'right',
      distance: 12
    },
    vertical: {
      position: 'top',
      distance: 60,
      gap: 10
    }
  },
  theme: 'material',
  behaviour: {
    autoHide: 5000,
    onClick: 'hide',
    onMouseover: 'pauseAutoHide',
    showDismissButton: true,
    stacking: 4
  },
  animations: {
    enabled: true,
    show: {
      preset: 'slide',
      speed: 300,
      easing: 'ease'
    },
    hide: {
      preset: 'fade',
      speed: 300,
      easing: 'ease',
      offset: 50
    },
    shift: {
      speed: 300,
      easing: 'ease'
    },
    overlap: 150
  }
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        BrowserModule,
        DragDropModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AutosizeModule,
        routing,
        FormsModule,
        NgxChessBoardModule.forRoot(),
        NotifierModule.withConfig(customNotifierOptions),
        MatIconModule,
        CreditCardDirectivesModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        NgApexchartsModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        ThermalPrintModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        NgbModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        ChartistModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
        MatDialogModule,
        FlexLayoutModule],
  entryComponents: [
    ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent,
    NotificationPopupComponent,
    NotificationConfirmationComponentComponent,
    CustomMessageItemDialogComponent,
    UploadImageDialogComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AlertComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    TimeAgoPipe,
    DropdownUserRolesComponent,
    DropdownCategoriesComponent,
    ChartOfUserAccountsComponent,
    YoutubeComponent,
    AppComponent,
    VideosListComponent,
    VideosSearchComponent,
    VideoPlayerComponent,
    VideosPlaylistComponent,
    VideoDurationPipe,
    VideoLikesViewsPipe,
    VideoNamePipe,
    LazyScrollDirective,
    HelpComponent,
    CreateUserComponent,
    AddCategoryComponent,
    CategoriesComponent,
    AddItemComponent,
    ViewCartComponent,
    ItemsByCategoryComponent,
    ItemsPageComponent,
    OrderHistoryComponent,
    DropdownBooleanSelectorComponent,
    DropdownItemOptionSelectorComponent,
    ViewOrdersComponent,
    TableSummaryComponent,
    DropdownTableSelectorComponent,
    DropdownFilterByItemSelectorComponent,
    SidebarMenuComponent,
    DropdownFilterByCategorySelectorComponent ,
    ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent,
    NotificationPopupComponent ,
    OrderHistoryDataTableComponent ,
    ServerOrderComponent,
    NotificationConfirmationComponentComponent,
    WaiterReadyOrderViewComponent ,
    DropdownLanguageSelectorComponent ,
    CustomMessageItemDialogComponent,
    CategoriesByItemComponent,
    KioskComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    UploadImageDialogComponent,
    addTipComponent,
    paymentReceiptComponent,
    PrinterListComponent,
    PaymentPendingScreenComponent,
    CreditCardPaymentScreenComponent
,
    DashboardComponent ,
    GamesComponent ,
    CloverAuthRouterComponent],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AuthGuardClover,
    AlertService,
    AuthenticationService,
    ViewCartComponent,
    UserService,
    YoutubeApiService,
    CloverAuthenticationService,
    YoutubePlayerService,
    CartService,
    PlaylistStoreService,
    ServerRequestService,
    NotificationService,
    BrowserNotificationService,
    addTipComponent,
    paymentReceiptComponent,
    PrinterListComponent,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true}

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

declare module '@angular/core' {

  interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
    ngModule: Type<T>;
    providers?: Provider[];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by changing

```
"ngx-chess-board": "^2.0.7",
```

to:

```
"ngx-chess-board": "2.0.7",
```